# MySQL Import from txt - Character Set

Tags: mysql, file-io, utf-8, phpmyadmin, character

I try to import data from a txt file into my database via PhpmyAdmin.
Below the query I use. Import works, but the query adds the replacement mark after each character, e.g. "Input1" string is uploaded as "�I�n�p�u�t�1" (could not find this behavior in any posting, yet).

Problem is that I dont know the character set of the txt file. Tried UTF8mb4/16/32, UCS2,ascii, big5 - no success.
If I save the txt manually as UTF-8 or as CSV, the upload works fine though. I intend to link this with a Cronjob for automatic procedure, hence manual adjustment is not a solution though.

Here is my code:

DELETE FROM TEST_2 WHERE 1; 
LOAD DATA INFILE '/share/.../Import SQL/A01.txt' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE TEST_2
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
IGNORE 1 LINES

Thanks for reading this - anybody any ideas?

Comment: That smells like some Microsoft format and/or UCS2.  Since you tried ucs2, please provide the details of how you did that.  The charset for the _client_ is the important one, not the charset for the table/column.  In particular, try the `LOAD` with `ucs2` instead of utf8.

Comment: I tried the following code for UCS2 import:

LOAD DATA INFILE '/share/.../Import SQL/A01.txt' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE TEST_2
CHARACTER SET UCS2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
IGNORE 1 LINES

Other than with UTF8 statement, this does import nothing (empty table), with no error message.

Answer (score 0):

Since the source seems to be in charset ucs2:

```
 LOAD DATA INFILE '/share/.../Import SQL/A01.txt'  -- ok as is
     REPLACE INTO TABLE TEST_2
     CHARACTER SET ucs2                            -- note
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY CONVERT(';' USING ucs2)  -- note
     IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Converting the `;` is on the assumption that it, too, is ucs2 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support, unfortunately none of the above worked for me.

I solved this in a different way now, by automatically converting the txt file to utf8 before running the upload query. One additional step unfortunately, but the only solution I figured out, since 'CHARACTER SET' within SQL did not provide a working solution.

Cronjob is uploading the data via mySQLi from the converted file.